# How to change tinyMCE editor resize handler position

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, editor, tinymce-plugins

By default tinyMCE editor resize handler is shown on the bottom right corner of the editor and it gets resized when it's dragged down from there.

[image]

Can you tell me whether there is a way for me to place tinyMCE editor resize handler at the top right corner of the editor and resize it by dragging the handler upward?

[image]